# How to add dataset to azure data factory using python requests script

Tags: python, azure, python-requests, azure-data-factory, data-manipulation

So I have a python script get-data.py that sends a request to a website (using the requests lib) with the necessary headers attached and writes the response to an excel spreadsheet. Now what I want to do is run this script in azure and pull it to my data factory so I can run some transformations on it.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this? Any relevant information would help.

Comment: Please ref this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook. 1. Run the python script with a notebook active. 2. call post request to an Rest API with REST active, put the return dataset in a blob storage.

Comment: Hi @Josh W, are that helpful for you?

Comment: Do you need the output in the Excel sheet?  You can probably pull the data direct from the website in ADF without the Python programme.  If you want to share your .py here I can help.